# Relate a set that is not a cartesian product to cartesian products

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider 3 sets
$$
A\equiv \{a_1,a_2,a_3\}
$$
$$
B\equiv \{b_1,b_2,b_3\}
$$
$$
C\equiv \{c_1,c_2,c_3\}
$$

Let $\mathcal{A}$ denote all possible subsets of $A$ excluding the empty set. Similarly, $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$. I.e.,

$$
\mathcal{A}\equiv \Big\{A, \{a_1\}, \{a_2\}, \{a_3\}, \{a_1,a_2\}, \{a_2, a_3\}, \{a_1,a_3\}\Big\}
$$

$$
\mathcal{B}\equiv \Big\{B, \{b_1\},\{b_2\}, \{b_3\},\{b_1,b_2\}, \{b_2, b_3\}, \{b_1,b_3\}\Big\}
$$

$$
\mathcal{C}\equiv \Big\{C, \{c_1\},\{c_2\}, \{c_3\},\{c_1,c_2\}, \{c_2, c_3\}, \{c_1,c_3\}\Big\}
$$
Some additional definitions are now introduced.

---

**Construction of $A\times B \times C$:**

Let $\times$ denote the cartesian product. 
$A\times B \times C$ is the collection of all ordered $3$-tuples from $A,B,C$, i.e.,
$$
A\times B \times C\equiv \Big\{(a_1,b_1,c_1),(a_1,b_2,c_1), (a_1,b_3,c_1),... \Big\}
$$

---

**Construction of $\mathcal{T}$:**

Consider $\mathcal{T}\equiv \mathcal{A}\times \mathcal{B}\times \mathcal{C}$. For example, an element $T\in \mathcal{T}$ is
$$
T\equiv \Big(\{a_1,a_2\}, \{b_3\} , \{c_1,c_2\}\Big) 
$$

Each $T\in \mathcal{T}$ is made of 3 "components". In the example above, the first component is $\{a_1,a_2\}$, the second is $\{b_3\}$, the third is $\{c_1,c_2\}$.

We rewrite each $T\in \mathcal{T}$ as the set of all possible ordered $3$-tuples that can be constructed from its $3$ components. Continuing the example above,
$$
T\equiv \overbrace{\Big(\{a_1,a_2\}, \{b_3\} , \{c_1,c_2\}\Big)}^{\text{Representation 1}}  \equiv \overbrace{\Big\{\overbrace{(a_1,b_3, c_1)}^{\text{ordered $3$-tuple}}, (a_2, b_3, c_1), (a_1,b_3, c_2), (a_2,b_3, c_2)\Big\} }^{\text{Representation 2}}
$$

---

**Construction of $\mathcal{M}$:**

We collect in $\mathcal{M}$ all the subsets of $A\times B\times C$  that cannot be part of $\mathcal{T}$. For example, 
$$
M\equiv \Big\{(a_1,b_3, c_1), (a_2, b_2, c_1)\Big\}
$$
$M$ is not an element of $\mathcal{T}$.

---

**Question**

It seems to be that the elements of $\mathcal{M}$ can be "categorised" into 2 separate groups: let $M$ denote a generic element of $\mathcal{M}$; let $M^c$ denote the complement of $M$ in $A\times B\times C$; we can have

(1) $M$ such that $M^c \in \mathcal{T}$. For example, $M\equiv A\times B\times C \setminus \Big\{(a_1,b_2,c_3)\Big\}$ where $A\times B\times C \setminus \Big\{(a_1,b_2,c_3)\Big\}$ is the complement of $\Big\{(a_1,b_2,c_3)\Big\}$ in $A\times B\times C$.

(2) $M$ such that $M^c\notin \mathcal{T}$. For example, $M\equiv A\times B\times C \setminus \Big\{(a_1,b_3,c_1), (a_2, b_2, c_3)\Big\}$.

My question is about group (2) and how I can relate a set in group (2) to $\mathcal{T}$.

More precisely: is there a way to rewrite an $M$ following in group (2) as if it was a cartesian product of sets?  Or, express it in a way that relates it to the elements of $\mathcal{T}$? For group (1), I am fine since I have  $M^c\in \mathcal{T}$. For group (2), I am looking for a relation with the elements in $\mathcal{T}$.

Comment: There is something wrong with notation. If each $M$ is a subset of $D = A \times B \times C$, how can $M^c = D \setminus M$ be not a subset of $D$? (Your example for (2) is not valid as $\big\{(a_1, b_3, c_1), (a_2, b_2, c_3)\big\}$ is pretty well $\subset D$.)

Comment: (Maybe you mean $M^c\in\mathcal{T}$ and resp. $M^c\notin\mathcal{T}$. But then I don't understand the question itself.)

Comment: @metamorphy apologies, there was a mistake. I have edited, please advise further if it seems still wrong to you. Thanks

Comment: So you're "building a ball out of cubes" (with, say, boolean operations)? Beware that, even in the finite case, $\mathcal{T}$ is "fairly small": $|\mathcal{T}| = (2^{|A|} - 1)(2^{|B|} - 1)(2^{|C|} - 1) \approx 2^{|A| + |B| + |C|}$ and $|\mathcal{M}\cup\mathcal{T}| = 2^{|A|\cdot|B|\cdot|C|}$.

Comment: But in that case each $M$ can be composed out of elements of $\mathcal{T}$ with a _finite_ number of operations (thus, there may be some interesting optimality-related problems). For infinite sets, you're left with a too broad situation I think.

Comment: @metamorphy Thanks a lot. Indeed, $\mathcal{T}$ is much smaller than $\mathcal{M}\cup \mathcal{T}$. In my real problem I have a bunch of inequalities involving each element of $\mathcal{M}\cup \mathcal{T}$ and I want to show that considering the inequalities involving each element of $\mathcal{T}$ is enough (so that I achieve a huge dimension reduction). To show that I need to relate each element of $\mathcal{M}$ to $\mathcal{T}$.  If you could post an answer, I would be very grateful. I don't need super-fancy things, just an expression that relates an $M$ of group (2) to $\mathcal{T}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is far from being complete (due to obvious reasons).

For finite $A, B, C$ there is a multitude of choices to represent a subset of $A \times B \times C$ through $A' \times B' \times C'$ with $A' \subseteq A$, $B' \subseteq B$ and $C' \subseteq C$ (the most trivial with $A', B', C'$ being singletons, of course). So you may need some criteria to choose "this over that". It may include the set operations allowed, their respective costs, the costs of selecting a particular subset of $A$ or $B$ or $C$, and whatever else.

Even just counting set-theoretic operations (union, intersection and complement) to reach a given subset of $A \times B \times C$ out of products of subsets of $A, B, C$ presents a fairly hard computational problem. With not too large sets, it can of course be solved using dynamic programming, and there are other methods, but don't expect too much. For instance, with $A = B = C = \{1, \ldots, n\}$ and $M = \{(x, y, z) : x + y + z \leqslant n\}$, you will still need $O(n^2)$ elements of $\mathcal{T}$ to get $M$.

So the question to you is what is the "measure of quality" (or complexity) of relations.

With infinite sets, counting operations is out of question. At the least, you enter the area of functional analysis, and at not the worst, you lose an ability to represent your $M$ exactly (from a computational point of view).

(If a representation of $M$ using singletons is all you need, then forget all of the above. Joking.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Take for example $M\equiv \{(a_1, b_1,c_1), (a_1,b_2,c_2), (a_1,b_1,c_2), (a_1,b_2,c_1), (a_2, b_1,c_1),(a_2,b_1,c_2)\}$. This set falls in group (2). How would you represent this set as a cartesian product $A'\times B'\times C'$? If I am interpreting your answer correctly, there are many ways to achieve this representation. Could you provide two ways for example?

Comment: I didn't say it is possible to represent $M$ as a _single_ cartesian product. Moreover, I gave an example of $M$ that may _require_ fairly _many_ cartesian products to get it out of those using set-theoretic operations.

Comment: OK, I see, thanks. I'm trying to picture some examples in my mind to understand better (I'm not a mathematician, sorry). Could you give me any example of a set $M$ of your choice falling in group (2) and show me how I can represent it as the result of (potentially multiple) cartesian product(s)?

Comment: But you have presented it already. Simplifying it extremely, put $A = B = \{1, 2\}$, $C = \{1\}$ and $M = \{(1, 2, 1), (2, 1, 1)\}$. Then $M$ is not a cartesian product, but it is a union of two (singletons).

Comment: OK, I see. So, let me repeat it in my terms to be sure I got it: you are saying that any subset of $A\times B\times C$ can be represented as the union/intersection/any other set operation of cartesian products. Correct?

Comment: Yes, of course. The "trivial example of singletons" is that any subset is a union (just union) of singletons (i.e. cartesian products of single-element subsets). Not that interesting example to you I suspect ;)

Comment: I see, then it is a matter of which representation it is convenient for what I need to show. OK, got it. Thanks. I might post another question on this.